# cipher inside and image

Tags: cryptanalysis

I have a short cipher of (33) characters , which is only ascii characters.
From this information. Is it possible to guess what kind of encryption was that?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this info](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) from our help center.

Answer (score 1):

The set of bijections from the set of words over an alphabet to itself is countable, therefore it ***is*** possible to guess the correct cipher in *finite time*. But you can never be sure you found the right one, since you can "decrypt" *literally **any*** plaintext from a given ciphertext without further constraints.